Error in Executing Docker Run command from Azure VMSS
I am trying to execute Neoload performance test scenario using docker from Azure VMSS. Below is the YAML code I am using
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: 2019vmss

steps:
- task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Docker 17.09.0-ce'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'docker --version'

- script: 
   docker run --rm -v "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)":/neoload-project -e SCENARIO_NAME=UPX_5_User_Load_test -e NEOLOADWEB_TOKEN=Token -e TEST_NAME=CI-smoke -e CONTROLLER_ZONE_ID=zodeid neotys/neoload-web-test-launcher

Pipeline is successful able to validate docker installation, but while executing docker run command is returning below error
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.32/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

When trying to google, I see few suggestion to run the command in administrative mode. But I believe all the task executed in pipeline are by default run in admin mode. Requesting for help to resolve.

What image is the VMSS agent pool using?
If it is a self-built image, how is docker installed when generating the image?

I am trying to run the image neotys/neoload-web-test-launcher which is available in docker hub

When i Did get childitem in powershell for the docker installation path. I only see docker.exe. I do not see any other files such as dockerd.exe .Probably I need to use different task for docker installation

Yes, reason why I asked about what image your pool 2019vmss is using, is because these steps indicate docker is already installed in the image, the DockerInstaller@0 task only installs the docker cli, not the docker engine. I would suspect your image does not have Docker Engine installed + service started properly, it would also require that the VSTS agent has sufficient permissions thereafter.

@VishalChepuri, What is the OS of your VMSS. Is it Windows? After installing Docker for Windows, Docker does not start automatically, it also does not start automatically at startup.

Yes is it Windows @BrightRan-MSFT

I tried running dockerd command, but widnows could not recognize the term

@VishalChepuri, Did you try the second way?

From the error message, it seems that the Docker daemon does not start on the WMSS instance. You can try to set up startup scripts via the Custom Script Extension to start Docker daemon:

If your VMSS is Windows OS, you can try one of the following ways:

Call the dockerd command in the startup scripts. Also see "Install server and client binaries on Windows".

If you have installed Docker Desktop on the VMSS, you can try to use the PowerShell script below to start Docker Desktop.
# startup.ps1

# By default, Docker Desktop is installed at "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker" on Windows.
Start-Process -FilePath "installation/path/to/Docker Desktop.exe"
Start-Service -Name com.docker.service




If your VMSS is Linux OS, like Ubuntu and Debian, you can use the command below. See "Start the daemon".
sudo systemctl start docker




